# How do I keep count in a column for the number of times an ID appears?

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssms

I have `user_id` in one column, `attempt_id` in another, along with various other data. The `attempt_id` is **unique** but `user_id` is not.

I would like to insert a column which puts down the number of times a `user_id` has appeared up to that point. So first time it appears, 1, second 2, etc.

I have attempted to do this with basic `count` functions, but that returns the total count in each instance, rather than a running count.

Is there a simple formula/trick which solves this issue? Running sums aren't really what I want, I want to search the column and see if this is the first instance of that `user_id` appearing.

Comment: You need to define which column defines a "first" instance of a `user_id` as actually being first.

Answer (score 0):

If you just want a count in a query, use a `row_number()`.  You require something that specifies the ordering of the rows -- that is presumably `attempt_id`:

```
select t.*,
       row_number() over (partition by user_id order by attempt_id) as seqnum
from t;
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the `attempt_id` increases with occurrence for a given user, you may try using `COUNT` as an analytic function:

```
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT user_id, attempt_id,
        COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY user_id ORDER BY attempt_id) cnt
    FROM yourTable
)

SELECT user_id, attempt_id
FROM cte
WHERE cnt = 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

Going out on a limb here, but based on your description above I assume you want to increase the attempt_id as you insert new rows.  So I am going to assume you are going to pass in user_id as a variable.  So you may consider this pattern:

```
CREATE TABLE #tmp(userid int, attempt_id int)
DECLARE @userid int 

SET @userid = 1

INSERT INTO #tmp 
SELECT @userid, (SELECT ISNULL(MAX(attempt_ID),0) + 1 from #tmp where userid = @userid)

select * from #tmp
```